# Before insert is not taking effect

Tags: apex, trigger, field-update, before-trigger, create-records

I'm trying to update an Email field on an sObject, we have lots of relationships, so using workflow rule is out of the question. Basically I need to send and email alert to the account owner of a related account. Thought triggers should do the trick, for some reason it's not working. Am I missing something on my code? I mean, I copied from another code I have and works.

Trigger snippet:

```
//Header
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before insert, after insert, before update, after update,before delete, after delete) {    

    new Triggers()
    .bind(Triggers.Evt.afterUpdate, new XBEBR_Sync2BPDealHandler())    
    .manage(); 

    if(LenovoUtility.isTriggerEnabled() ){ 

        OpportunityTriggerHandler handler = new OpportunityTriggerHandler();

        handler.newRecordList = trigger.new;
        handler.oldRecordList = trigger.old;
        handler.newRecordMap = trigger.newMap;
        handler.oldRecordMap = trigger.oldMap;    
        if(trigger.isBefore){
            if(trigger.isInsert){ 
                OpportunityTriggerHandler.setPartnerManagerEmail(Trigger.New);
            }
            if(trigger.isUpdate){ handler.onBeforeUpdate(); }
            //if(trigger.isDelete){ handler.onBeforeDelete(); }
        }
```

Handler method:

```
public static void setPartnerManagerEmail (List<Opportunity> oppList) {
    Set<Id> partnerAccounts = new Set<Id> ();
    for (Opportunity o : oppList) {
        partnerAccounts.add(o.Partner_Account__c);
    }

    Map <Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id,Account>([select id, Owner.Email from Account where id in :partnerAccounts]);
    for (Opportunity o : (List<Opportunity>) oppList) {
        o.EmailPartnerAccountManager__c = accountMap.get(o.Partner_Account__c).Owner.Email;
    }
} ...
```

The selection on Account is to get the right email address. I found no other way of retrieving it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you add trigger heading code? does it have before insert keyword and is it also activated?

Comment: so Opportunity.PartnerAccountManager is null?  or is non-null and no email is sent?

Comment: The trigger is firing, if I insert a debug line after assign the variable, it prints the right value.  It seems it's not committing right. After the trigger the EmailPartnerAccountManager field continues blank.

Comment: What does `LenovoUtility.isTriggerEnabled` do? What about the binding above that line? Do you have any  other workflows or `Process Builder` flows which could be interfering?

Comment: It enables or disables the triggers org wide. But I figured it out. I'll right the answer right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,

It's quite a complex architecture, there's this trigger, that creates a new object, this new object has a trigger that updates the first one, but for some reason, instead of updating it was making the following:

```
Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
opp.ID = oldOpp.Id;
```

And procedded on setting the fields. That's why the field I was setting was blank, it was being reinitialized later.